# webpackでライブラリを非commonjs環境として読み込みたい

Tags: javascript

一部のパッケージが採用しているrequire関数が、標準的なrequire.jsやcommonjsのそれとは非互換のため、webpackで正しく動かないことが‌​あります。

自分が認識しているのは Raphaël.js と getsentry/raven-js です。

この問題を解決するために、コードの方にパッチを当てるよりも、外部からのrequireでファイル的には連結しつつも、普通のscriptタグで読み込んだ時と同じように、requireポリフィルでラップしない非commonjs環境として読み込みたいケースがあります。どなたかこの方法をご存じないでしょうか。

raw-loaderを使ってテキストとして読み込んだJSをevalすればよいのはわかっていますが、さすがに汚すぎる気がしています。

[webpack/raw-loader](https://github.com/webpack/raw-loader)

Comment: 出だしの部分がわかりにくいので、
「一部のパッケージが採用しているrequire関数が、標準的なrequire.jsやcommonjsのそれとは非互換のため、webpackで正しく動かないことがあります。」
と修正しようと考えているのですがいかがでしょう? @mizchi

Comment: 修正しときました。まずそうなら教えてください。

Answer (score 1):

汚いのは変わらないかもしれませんが、以下でどうでしょうか？

Raphaelでしか試していないので、もしかするとライブラリごとに調整が必要かもしれません。

同一ディレクトリに以下の３つのファイルがあるとき:
index.js, raphael.js, webpack.config.js

index.js

```
require('raphael');

var paper = Raphael(10, 50, 320, 200);
var circle = paper.circle(50, 40, 10);
circle.attr("fill", "#f00");
circle.attr("stroke", "#fff");
```

webpack.config.js

```
var fs = require('fs');

module.exports = {
  externals: [
    function(context, request, callback) {
      if (/raphael/.test(request)) {
        var src = fs.readFileSync(request + '.js');
        return callback(null, "(function(module){" + src + "}.bind(window)())");
      }
      return callback();
    }
  ]
};
```